# Html/CSS size images

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to display photos in a same fixed size (which I added via the form using carieerwave):
[articles with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNXBc.png).

This is my code:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <% @posts.take(4).each do |post| %>
          <div class="carda"  style="width: 500px; float:left; margin: 20px; height: 430px;">
            <div class="card-content">
              <%= link_to image_tag(post.image_url, width: 500, height: 250), post %>
              <p class="title" style="margin-top: 5px; color:black">
      <%= raw link_to post.title, post  %>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not know why they have other sizes

Comment: Give a full jsfiddle example or if you have it hosted somewhere a link to inspect. Seems like you are setting a fixed width already

Comment: @StefanBob 
I do not have it on the server and do not shout on js fiddle because the application uses Rails and it will not be loaded.

Comment: @derek2 can you paste in the outputted HTML on your page when it's rendered in the browser?

Comment: Even without looking I can say get rid of the floats and put display: flex; on your .container and see if your widths are working

Comment: Tried to flush the browser cache?

Comment: @AminShahGilani https://www.paste.org/93363

Comment: @StefanBob But I want 2 pictures next to each other in a row, and the pictures are still different sizes https://imgur.com/a/bCk4ikJ

Answer (score 0):

I would say in this situation you want to just have images that are the same dimensions if not the same height. Otherwise you'll end up with this:

```css
.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card {}

.card-image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.card-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Alternative with BG images */

.card-image-bg {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.card:first-of-type .card-image-bg {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
}

.card:nth-of-type(2) .card-image-bg {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/250x190");
}

.card:last-of-type .card-image-bg {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/400x400");
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
      <p class="title">Image 1 caption 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x190"></div>
      <p class="title">Image 2 caption 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400"></div>
      <p class="title">Image 3 caption 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image-bg"></div>
      <p class="title">Image 1 caption 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image-bg"></div>
      <p class="title">Image 2 caption 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image-bg"></div>
      <p class="title">Image 3 caption 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use scss no css